# Can two fields be isomorphic but have a different set of automorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

More specifically, is it possible that two fields are isomorphic yet one of the fields has only the trivial automorphism while the other field has at least one nontrivial automorphism?

I think the answer is no because isomorphic (to me) means "the same" and the number of automorphisms should fall under the category of "sameness".

I think the answer is yes because Q(2^(1/3)) is isomorphic to Q(2^(1/3)*zeta_3) since both of these fields are isomorphic to Q[x]/(x^3 - 2).  But Q(2^(1/3)) has no nontrivial automorphisms because where would you map 2^(1/3)?  right?

While, Q(2^(1/3)*zeta_3) has an automorphism that maps 2^(1/3)zeta_3 to 2^(1/3)zeta_3^2.  right?

Comment: Can you write $\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta^2$ as an element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt[3]{2}\zeta]$? I can't.

Comment: @ Unit OK  Thanks, I can't either.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. They are "the same", so they have "the same" set of automorphisms. (This isn't *why*, just affirming your intuition.)

Comment: @ MPW  Thanks.  I see now, as the comment by Unit suggests, that what is wrong in my statements above is that there is no nontrivial automorphism on Q(2^(1/3)*zeta_3^2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given fields $K_1$ and $K_2$ and an isomorphism $\varphi : K_1 \to K_2$ and a nontrivial automorphism $f : K_1 \to K_1$, then $\varphi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1} : K_2 \to K_2$ is a nontrivial automorphism.